# Is it appropriate to register for a "Dev" app key?

Tags: discussion, placeholder, api-key, registration

When an app is in early development stages, it is quite common not to have an Icon, a Name, a Website, or even a description.

I'm considering registering one key which I could use in all my Alpha apps which may or may not get off the ground. Once an app goes Beta or RC of course a dedicated key would be requested. This approach would be to used to overcome the daily `No Key` limit during development.

Is this practice discouraged? Is the info collected for app registration used for some master app list somewhere which I'd risk polluting with my non-app key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you revisit your app registration, you can edit and update it.

So, once you *need* a key for development purposes go ahead and register one and just fill in more information as you're able.

Don't register an "all purpose" dev key, keep it per app.

Comment: I see. That works.