# Can I apply the API Key first and do the application later?

Tags: support, discussion, api-key

I don't have an application to submit at the moment, but can I apply the key first?

Comment: Ya, this would be good.

Comment: ... and so would removing the `app` tag from your question.

Comment: Similar to http://stackapps.com/questions/14/is-it-appropriate-to-register-for-a-dev-app-key

Comment: Thanks @Franci, Yeah similar, I think I will try that way.

Comment: @YOU: Do you mean ***apply for*** an API key? I assume you're not applying it ***to*** anything? I would just edit your question but I don't want to mess it up if I didn't understand something.

Comment: @hippietrail, I don't remember how was the API key request method wroks. So may be you could just edit it, if my question is grammatically wrong or kind of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't register for a key until you need it.

See **["How API Keys Work"](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work)** for more about API keys.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I got it. I don't want dummy application appears on app tab too.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need an API key until your app goes live. For small traffic amounts (under 300 requests/day) you can [use the API without the key](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api) to test your app:

> ### Do I need an API key?
>
> A single IP can only make a limited number of requests per day to the API. This limit is determined at first request time, and is dependent upon the presence of an API key.
>
> API daily limits:
>
> Key: 10,000
>   No Key: 300
>
> The `No Key` limit is meant to facilitate experimentation, not for deployed apps.

Requests with invalid or revoked keys are not completed, they are not stepped down to the `No Key` limit.

Comment: If I run out 300 requests, should I change my IP address? :)

Comment: But looks like this is the answer, make sense though.