# Bounty question collector

Tags: support, questions, app-request, script-request

I want to write a script to collate all bounty questions from all Stack Exchange sites.

I have heard of Tampermonkey and I have no server access.
Could someone explain how I should go about writing a script with read-only access to SE sites, bot them all for their bounty questions and then present the information in a method I can interpret?

Comment: I think that the database is updated once a week, so not a good option. Never tried anything with bounties using the API but should be the way to go. Check the [frontpage right column](http://stackapps.com/): `Get Started`. You'll be able to query the API online.

Comment: @brasofilo; is there a preferred method to query the database, e.g. CVS, SSH, Powerpoint(?) - does SE have a comm-query program?

Comment: Why do you want this?  Is it just to collect data or do you want to try and pounce on those bounties while they are still fresh?  ... The former is easy, the latter requires looping through up to 300 sites. ... What about meta sites?  Non-English sites?  Etc.  This question is too vague in its current form.

Comment: @BrockAdams; to find available bounties automatically without having to trawl through all 300 sites manually, or guessing where the rep is at

Comment: @BrockAdams; i've got another idea as well - in order to get Civic Duty badges i've been religiously voting on sites - something i feel could also be automated

Comment: You cannot automate voting with read-only access. ... Also, are you the guy that's been upvoting every question on this site, including real turkeys that are closed and should be **burned with holy fire**?

Comment: @BrockAdams; not on this site - and I use discretion

Comment: Anyway, this is not particularly hard.  Basically, your app would loop through your list of sites and call  [/questions/featured](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions) for each one. You'd want to filter and cache the results but no server is required.

Comment: @BrockAdams; thanks, but how do i connect to the SE server?

Comment: Standard AJAX request. See http://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api

Comment: @BrockAdams; don't want to state the obvious, but isn't AJAX server-side?

Comment: No.  The whole point is that it's client side.  But it *does* fetch data from a server.  It's pretty basic and usually well documented in whatever language you program in.

Comment: @BrockAdams; and do you have a particular program to do this, say your personnel favorite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30127/discussion-between-brock-adams-and-jon-mark-perry).

Comment: @BrockAdams; actually I think I have resolved the issue. thanks for your help

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269020/158100)