# I'm having a hard time finding resources for using Stack Overflow's API in Python to query some questions

Tags: support, api

I can just go through documentation but it'd be a time saver if I could find some sort of tutorial or intro or anything. Does anybody happen to have any resources, notes, or code examples they could give out?

Edit:
I guess to clarify: I don't know how to use Stack Overflow's API in Python, does anyone know how?

Comment: Specifically this answer https://stackapps.com/a/7169/42239. Related https://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api?noredirect=1&lq=1