# Can the no-key request limit be increased to 1000 for a certain amount of time?

Tags: discussion, api-key

Can the no-API-key request limit be increased to 1000 for a certain amount of time - maybe 1-2 weeks?

Comment: for what purpose? why not just generate an API key and use that?

Comment: @Jeff, I am currently testing various queries, don't have application to submit yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should register a Key.

Quoting the [Key documentation](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work):

> **When should I use a key?**
>
> The No Key limit is meant for light
>   experimentation and simple development
>   work. *The instant you need the higher
>   limit, it is acceptable to register
>   for a key*.Your application does not need to be in a releasable - even an alpha - state.

I would also check this question: [Is it appropriate to register for a “Dev” app key?](https://stackapps.com/questions/14/is-it-appropriate-to-register-for-a-dev-app-key)

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have application yet, currently doing some experimentation but its not light, and help pages also decrease the counter, so I am just want a few more to test temporarily.